# Understanding the Page Visibility API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a functionality where if a user opens our application, goes to another tab and comes back to our application after 30 minutes, I need to reload / refresh the page.

I am trying to use the page visibility API & set from time and to time and if difference if greater than 30 minutes reload the page.

Below is a sample code(its more like pseudo code for the purpose of the question)

```
(function() {
  var lastRequest, currentRequest, seconds;
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
   console.log(document.hidden, document.visibilityState);
      if(document.visibilityState == true) {
        currentRequest = Date.now();
        seconds = parseInt((currentRequest-lastRequest)/1000);
        #if seconds greater than 1800 refresh the page 
      } else {
        lastRequest = Date.now();
      }
  }, false);
})();
```

but I have noticed that if I duplicate the page of our application(open the same page again by right clicking current open tab and click duplicate), `the events of visibilitychange no longer get triggered on the duplicated tab`.

Can anyone please suggest if it's supposed to work this way or may be i am making some mistake.

I am testing this in `Chrome`

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using to test this?

Comment: I am testing in Chrome